# How can I explain to my 5-year-old that I need to be alone if I am showering?

Tags: primary-schooler, communication, bathing, mother, girls

I'm having a difficult time sometimes with my 5-year-old daughter understanding when I need privacy such as when I take a shower or need to put body cream on afterwards, dry up etc. If I explain it to her and nicely close the door she gets extremely mad screams and cries. How do I circumvent this?

It usually doesn't happen during the day as my husband will keep her distracted downstairs, but this morning she got up earlier as I was preparing for work and caught me in the shower and didn't want to leave when I got out, even after I kissed her good morning and calmly handled the situation.  I feel very guilty, but I want to teach her what privacy is and that our bodies should be private at times. I don't want her watching me as a naked woman while I'm doing private things.

My husband thinks she's too attached to me and that this should not be!  I let her see me dress quickly or if we go to a pool swimming of course but I don't want this to be the norm at home.

Comment: Hi Sue! Looks like you inadvertently made two accounts, I've merged them - you can now comment on and edit your question as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try explaining it sometime when you're *not* in the middle of the situation that when we go potty or use the shower that we should have privacy and that she should respect that. Then try to show her the same privacy (within reason) while she is showering/changing/pottying.

Also, a lock on the bathroom door might be in order.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :-) Yes, you're right - explaining in the heat of the moment DOES NOT work! lol  I have explained it to her when she's calm but I'll repeat more. I do lock the door but she gets upset when she can't open it.  Although, I must say this situation tends to occur only in the morning --once the day goes on and she's busy downstairs and I happen to take a shower upstairs she doesn't seem to follow me upstairs anymore.  I have also started showing her privacy when she's in the bathroom by leaving her alone while she's on the toilet and occasionally other times when I can.

Comment: Well, and with it happening more in the morning, is it starting with her morning routine being thrown off by the bathroom being locked? That may be part of the frustration if so.

Comment: Generally she's still sleeping when I shower in the morning or she's already downstairs and has eaten breakfast. These situations are not often but when they occur it seems traumatic for her! :-( True, I think it's a combination of her morning routine being thrown off and her feeling that I'm "hers" and that she is privy to everything about mommy. Thanks again for your comment!